# Ubuntu server 12.10 dhcp configuration

Tags: server

When installing Ubuntu server12.10 I am not connected to internet and while installing I chose manually configure network. Now i need my server to be connected to internet. please help me..... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setup to configure network manually then go to

```
 nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

It will be like this

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address ..
 netmask
 gateway
 network
 broadcast
```

You need to change it

```
 auto lo 
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
 #comment out the lines below this and Save the file
```

Then run

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

You will get the ip from dhcp server if you are connected to it.